# how to use timer in uitableview?

Tags: uitableview, nstimer, countdown, nstimeinterval

I am getting millisecond and i want to convert that millisecond to day,hours,minutes,second and display and want to display it in uiTableview. and i want to update that timer every second..

i had try this code using uiTableview delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
NSInteger totleTime = [[[productListDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"_auction_duration"] integerValue];


         totleTime =  totleTime - timerValue ;


         long days = (totleTime) / (60  * 60 * 24);
         long hours = (totleTime - days  * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60);
         long minuts = (totleTime - days * 60 * 60  * 24 - hours * 60 * 60) / 60;
         long seconds = (totleTime - days * 60 * 60 * 24 - hours * 60  *60 - minuts * 60);

 NSLog(@"seconds : %.f minutes : %.f hours : %.f days : %.f ", seconds, minuts, hours, days);
```

I had used this method for call method and update tableview. but its not working so suggest me another option or tell me what i had done wrong in this code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to reload your tableView every second. First of all, let me say that it is a bad idea. If your tableView is being reloaded then the user will not be able to see anything. Having said that, you can use a timer with a certain interval that calls a method. That method can decide when to reload the tableView.

**EDIT**

From your last comment, I understand that you are trying to display a countdown timer in a tableview cell. For that purpose, you don't need to reload the tableview. You only have to update the datasource and reload the row that is displaying the counter. Something along these lines.

The code snippet below is in Swift 2

```
//Call a method named tick() every second
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func tick() {

    //DO YOUR CALCULATIONS HERE TO CALCULATE YOUR DAYS, MINUTES, etc. THEN CALL THE FOLLOWING METHOD

    tblView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: {rowNumber}, inSection: {sectionNumber})], withRowAnimation: .None)

    //ALSO MAKE SURE YOUR cellForRowAtIndexPath IS CORRECTLY SETTING THE CELL VALUES
}
```

Don't forget to `invalidate` the timer when you're finished with it

Comment: i have try this but not get proper output

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as to what exactly you tried, what was the expected output, and what was the actual output?

Comment: i can get millisecond  this:- 5426977  and output is blove :-

seconds : 37 minutes : 29 hours : 19 days : 62 

but now can show user 
1.  62: 19  : 29 : 37 

2. 62: 19  : 29 : 36 

3. 62: 19  : 29 : 35

Comment: Questions need to be clear and to the point. You have not provided me with much to go on here. I have no idea what 5426977 means in this scenario. Please make sure your question is well documented and mentions all the relevant details.

Comment: totleTime= 5426977;

every second call method and reload table and pulse values.

 timerValue += 1000

Comment: but i display a countdown timer in all tableview cell.

Answer (score 1):

i have get solve this issues.

1.At initial i had set timer is 1 second.

```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

2.Every Second Call Method and change value and reload tableview.

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
     timerValue += 1;
    [ProductListTableView reloadData];
}
```

3. now calculate remaining time in uitableView deleget method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSInteger totleTime = [[[productListDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"_auction_duration"] integerValue];


         totleTime =  totleTime - timerValue ;


         long days = (totleTime) / (60  * 60 * 24);
         long hours = (totleTime - (days * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60) ;

         long minuts = (totleTime - (days * 60 * 60  * 24) - (hours * 60 * 60)) / 60;
         long seconds = (totleTime - (days * 60 * 60 * 24) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minuts * 60));



        cell.saleTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Sold %ld:%ld:%ld:%ld",[[productListDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"sales_qty"], days,hours,minuts,seconds];
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know timeValue's meanings, if timeValue assume system time. you can write a timer to reload tableView's data.